# ViewFlipper causing application to crash on Back Pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewflipper

I have a two view flippers in my fragment, in one I flip 3 views and in the other 2.  I flip all views and then proceed to the next fragment.  If on this next fragment I hit the back button, the app crashes with this in the logcat:

```
Activity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@41e58cc0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I have researched this a lot and the common solution is to implement a custom view flipper, which I have done:

```
public class CustomViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
    public CustomViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        try {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            stopFlipping();
        }
    }
}
```

However this doesn't resolve the issue.  Has anyone been able to resolve this?  I know that there is a bug in view flipper, if anyone could help with this I'd appreciate it

Comment: Has nobody encountered this before?  If I can't get this to work without crash, I'll need to remove it and work with nested fragments which will be a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was reproduced on screen rotate when `viewFlipper` runs animation. By some reason `onDetachedFromWindow()` method is not called on such `viewFlipper`.

Calling `m_viewFlipper.clearAnimation()` in `MyActivity.onPause()` method saves me.